# When stopping an android emulator in eclipse, is all the cache cleared or does eclipse store it for the next emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, caching, android-emulator

When running an emulator in eclipse for android, when I close this emulator, make some changes in my code and launch another emulator to test it, is the cache from the first emulator deleted, or does eclipse store it and pass it to the new emulator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data will still be there.

More specificelly, it won't be saved and restored by Eclipse, but by the Emulator's image. The image is a file that contains all the data that would lie on a real Android device's ROM. It's an essential part of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

the data doesn't go away from your emulator, when you running your application using emulator, the emulator will be saving your application, even after you close the emulator and open it again, you still can find your previous application in the list of app in your emulator

Answer (score 0):

When you launch an app on emulator, it gets installed on that Emulator, n later when u use this same emulator, you'll get that app just like on mobile. **And when you change your code, and again launch emulator, it again gets installed and then that app starts.**